# How to get only one digit or character for the month of the year in Oracle-sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a question... need expert advise. I am working in SQL Developer

For a label printing, only one character is allocated for month... so 1-9 is for months Jan-Sep, A-C are from months Oct-Dec.

I am trying DECODE function as below:

```
Select decode(to_char(sysdate,'mon')
, 'jan',1
 ,'feb',2
  ,'oct',A
 ,'nov',B
 ,'dec',C)
```

but I get error C is an invalid identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help point you in the right direction?

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'mon') date_part_mon
      ,decode(to_char(sysdate,'mon') 
      ,'jan','1'
      ,'feb','2'
      ,'oct','A'
      ,'nov','B'
      ,'dec','C') date_part_code
  FROM dual
```

Comment: Glad to help...and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please mark this as the accepted answer? Here is how and why: [Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)